# Regex replace text between delimiters in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to fix some text that lies between delimiters for the following cases:
Case 1: `{12345}` (numbers between curlies) should become `item_12345` (added 'item_', removed braces).
Case 2: `[999]` (numbers between square brackets) should become `total_999`

So this string: `{242424} from X [100] bulks, linked to {57575757} from Y for [500] units`
should appear like this: `item_242424 from X total_100 bulks, linked to item_57575757 from Y for total_500 units`

How can this be done with regex?

Comment: What have you come up with so far?

Comment: Hi, pretty much nothing. I don't know how to separate the text from the tags and how to define multiple patterns with multiple replacements. This is a complete black hole for me and I wasn't able to find any answer

Comment: If you had spent even couple of hours, assuming you are new to programming/regex, should have something to share here.

Comment: Well, following the answer below, I guess my error was placing the parentheses outside the curlies. This gave me an undesirable result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
s = '{123} and [456]'

s = re.sub(r'\{(.+?)\}', r'foo_\1', s)
s = re.sub(r'\[(.+?)\]', r'bar_\1', s)

print s
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to include the other set (square brackets) in the same expression? Or should I use a second re.sub?

Comment: Since your replacements are different, another re.sub will be easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> curly = re.compile('\{([0-9]+)\}')
>>> square = re.compile('\[([0-9]+)\]')
>>> s = "{242424} from X [100] bulks, linked to {57575757} from Y for [500]"
>>> re.sub(square, lambda x: 'total_'+x.group(1), re.sub(curly, lambda x: 'item_
'+x.group(1),s))
'item_242424 from X total_100 bulks, linked to item_57575757 from Y for total_50
0'
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly solves my problem with one ".sub", but it is a bit complicated.