# Replace text between 2 strings

Tags: python, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace text between 2 strings using Python or sed. I read  all what I found on Stack Overflow, but my skills don't seems to be enough to adapt what I found to my problem.

I have 2 files :

1. Courses.txt:

   ```
   Course = bla
   Room number(1)
   url http://foobar
   ```
2. dst.txt:

   ```
   //Start

   Course = foo
   Room Number(2)
   url http://bar

   //End
   ```

My goal is to replace what is between `//Start` and `//End` in `dst.txt` with what is read in `Courses.txt`.

I looked here :

- [sed/awk/bash to replace text between two strings with external file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467930/sed-awk-bash-to-replace-text-between-two-strings-with-external-file-contents)
- [Replace all text between 2 strings python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16159969/replace-all-text-between-2-strings-python)
- [Regex replace text between delimiters in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515176/regex-replace-text-between-delimiters-in-python)

but was not able to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import re
 with open('Courses.txt', 'r') as f1, open('dst.txt', 'r') as f2:
        text = f1.read()
        text2 = f2.read()
        ntext = re.sub(r'(//Start.*?\n+)(.*)(//End)',r'\1' + text + r'\3',text2, flags=re.M|re.DOTALL)

    with open('dst.txt', 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(ntext)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '\#^//Start#,\#^//End#{
   \#^//End# !d
   r Courses.txt
   }' dst.txt
```

Explanation:

- for every thing between *start* and *end* (`\#//^Start#,\#//^End#`) using a different delimiter `\#` than default `/`, execute sub action inside `{}`

  - for all line except *end* (`\#^//end# !`), delete the line (`d`) [and cycle to next line]
  - [if not the case, so contain *end*], replace by (read) content of file Course.txt

Comment: Hi NeronLeVelu, First of all thanks for your answer. Then I just copy/past your answer and I just had an echo of what there is in dst.txt, but nothing replaced.

Comment: The echo was due to an error of mine, but unfortunately for me, once corrected, the code did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i know this late but here is my solution:
note this will overwrite the content of original file so make sure to back it up

```
f = open("test.txt","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
f = open("test.txt","w")
start=False
for line in lines:
    if line.strip() == "starting string":
        f.write(line)
        start=True
    elif line.strip() == "ending string":
        f.write("line1 content\nline2 content\n")
        start=False
    if start == False:
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```